# YII Cannot Find Table

Tags: mysql, yii, wamp

i am working in Yii using WAMP-MYSQL database.i have created tables as-

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `balaee_dev`.`country` (
  `countryId` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `country` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`countryId`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `country_UNIQUE` (`country` ASC) )
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

When I test the project [here](http://test.balaee.com/balaee/index.php/KnowledgePortal/country/getcountry) - it's giving me this error:

"The table "country" for active record class "country" cannot be found in the database", though this table exists in database. I am getting this error for each and every controller. Here is my config file:

```
<?php

// This is the configuration for yiic console application.
// Any writable CConsoleApplication properties can be configured here.
return array(
    'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
    'name'=>'My Console Application',
    // application components
    'components'=>array(
        'db'=>array(
            'connectionString' => 'sqlite:'.dirname(__FILE__).'/../data/testdrive.db',
        ),
        // uncomment the following to use a MySQL database

        'db'=>array(
            'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=balaee_dev',
            'emulatePrepare' => true,
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ),

    ),
);
```

And i have main.php as-

```
<?php

// uncomment the following to define a path alias
// Yii::setPathOfAlias('local','path/to/local-folder');

// This is the main Web application configuration. Any writable
// CWebApplication properties can be configured here.
return array(
    'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
    'name'=>'My Balaee Application',
    // preloading 'log' component
    'preload'=>array('log'),
    // autoloading model and component classes
    'import'=>array(
        'application.models.*',
        'application.components.*',
        'application.modules.KnowledgePortal.*',
        'application.modules.QuestionBank.*',
        //'application.modules.UserAuthentication.*',
        'application.plugins.*',
            'application.extensions.noaaWeather.*',

    ),
    'modules'=>array(
        //Question Bank Module
        'QuestionBank'=>array(),
        //Social Networking Module
        'SocialNetworking'=>array(),
        //Knowledge Portal Module
        'KnowledgePortal'=>array(),
        // uncomment the following to enable the Gii tool
        'gii'=>array(
            'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
            'password'=>'root',
            // If removed, Gii defaults to localhost only. Edit carefully to taste.
            'ipFilters'=>array('127.0.0.1','::1'),
            //'ipFilters'=>array('204.93.172.30'),
        ),
    ),
    // application components
    'components'=>array(
        'user'=>array(
            // enable cookie-based authentication
            'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
        ),

        'mailer' => array(
                'class' => 'application.extensions.mailer.EMailer',
                'pathViews' => 'application.views.email',
                'pathLayouts' => 'application.views.email.layouts'
        ),
        'curl'=>array(
        'class' => 'application.extensions.curl.Curl',
        ),
        'params'=>array(
        'noaaWeather.cachePath' => 'protected/extensions/noaaWeather/cache'
        ),

        // uncomment the following to enable URLs in path-format
        'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'rules'=>array(
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            ),
        ),
/*
        'db'=>array(
            'connectionString' => 'sqlite:'.dirname(__FILE__).'/../data/testdrive.db',
        ),
*/

    'db'=>array(
            //'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=balaee_dev',
            'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=204.93.172.30;dbname:shailani_balaee_dev',
            //'emulatePrepare' => true,
            'username' => 'shailani_bdev',
            'password' => 'nTRXpfuH8wmjx5hV',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ),      
        // uncomment the following to use a MySQL database

        'db'=>array(
            'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=balaee_dev',
            'emulatePrepare' => true,
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ),

        'errorHandler'=>array(
            // use 'site/error' action to display errors
            'errorAction'=>'site/error',
        ),
        'log'=>array(
            'class'=>'CLogRouter',
            'routes'=>array(
                array(
                    'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                    'levels'=>'error, warning',
                ),
                // uncomment the following to show log messages on web pages
                /*
                array(
                    'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
                ),
                */
            ),
        ),
    ),

    // application-level parameters that can be accessed
    // using Yii::app()->params['paramName']
    'params'=>array(
        // this is used in contact page
        'adminEmail'=>'webmaster@example.com',
    ),
);
```

So please can someone guide me what changes i need to make?

Comment: you posted the config for your console application(`console.php`). Post the contents of `main.php`

Comment: comment or delete this line: 'db'=>array(
            'connectionString' => 'sqlite:'.dirname(__FILE__).'/../data/testdrive.db',
        ),

Comment: Thanks sir for reply..i have edited code by including main.php file...

Comment: @BànChânTrần: Sir i removed code as per your suggestion.But its still giving same error.

Comment: i think you want to use 2 database... but you just use one name "db" in main.php... reference this : http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/123/multiple-database-support-in-yii/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you're using MySQL. So the sqlite line in your configuration shall not appear. 
Provided the tables have been actually created in your MySql database (I guess you can see them in MySQL Workbench or in PHPMyAdmin):

- remove this line
- re-run the model / CRUD / whatever generation.

If your connection string and params are OK, it should work.

If it doesn't, feel free to copy here the related errors logs : Yii, MySql and Apache's logs can contain useful information.